# ERROR: module.exports = __webpack_require__.p .... module is not defined

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

when i upadate webpack from 4 to 5, the error existed.

```
ERROR in   Error: F:\cloud-music\public\index.html:13
  module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + "static/media/javascript,__webpack_public_path__ = htmlWebpackPluginPublicPath;.93bce551.bin";
  ^
  ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

however, when i look into the `index.html`, there is no any `module`
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJI8n.png)

please the error message [more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAF3r.png)

here is how i defined the htmlWebpackPlugin

```
           new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
                Object.assign({}, {
                        inject: true,
                        template: paths.appHtml,
                    },
                    isEnvProduction ? {
                        minify: {
                            removeComments: true,
                            collapseWhitespace: true,
                            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                            useShortDoctype: true,
                            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                            removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                            keepClosingSlash: true,
                            minifyJS: true,
                            minifyCSS: true,
                            minifyURLs: true,
                        },
                    } :
                    undefined
                )
```

thank you! Dmitry Nesterenko
please check my code, I'm new in webpack

```
{
      loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
      exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.json$/], 
      // was ---- exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
      options: {
            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      },
},
```

I changed the code as above, however, i didn't work.
And when I remove all of them, it worked! I don't know why???

Comment: Post the full code, so we can help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a plugin's bug. Fix described in this Issue:

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1589

Comment: however link may answer the question, consider adding most valuable information directly to the post.

Comment: not sure what the solution is from the link. I exclude `html` from `flie-loader` but the issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

I had:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
  exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
  options: {
     name: `${buildMode.ASSET_PREFIX}[name].[hash:8].[ext]`,
     esModule: false,
  },
}
```

changing esModule to true fixed the issue fixed it for me:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
  exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
  options: {
     name: `${buildMode.ASSET_PREFIX}[name].[hash:8].[ext]`,
     esModule: true,
  },
}
```